# How to make an accessible list in a web component?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, web-component, wai-aria, nvda

I built a select web component (a button toggling a list of options in a dropdown). It is actually 2 components: `x-select` and `x-option`. I have a `div role="list"` in `x-select` (inside its shadow DOM, wrapping the `<slot />`) and each `x-option` has a `role="listitem"`.
With Shadow DOM enabled for both components, NVDA (with Chrome) is not picking up the text content of the options; it announces something like "list item (6 of 12)".

```html
<!-- x-select -->
<button aria-controls="listbox-id">Select an option</button>
<div role="listbox" id="listbox-id">
    <slot />
</div>


<!-- x-option -->
<Host role="option">
  <slot />
</Host>


<!-- usage -->
<x-select>
  <x-option>Red</x-option>
  <x-option>Blue</x-option>
  <x-option>Green</x-option>
</x-select>
```

This seems to be caused by the fact that the `list` is within the shadow DOM of `my-select`, while `listitem`s are in the light DOM (slotted).

NVDA does read the options text when shadow DOM is disabled for the option component, but this is not a satisfying solution for me.

Is this a bug in NVDA? Is there a workaround, or is there a better way to build this component?

**UPDATE**
After further testing, I noticed my code works in VoiceOver/Safari, NVDA/Firefox and NVDA/JAWS, and fails in NVDA/Chrome, JAWS/Chrome, NVDA/Edge and JAWS/Edge. Seems like a bug in Chromium (which powers both Chrome and Edge). I filed a bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1214277)

Comment: If application X doesn't dive into shadowDOM it is a missing feature, not a bug.

Comment: Check the Accessibility Object Model (accessibility inspector in Chrome and Firefox) and see what it has, the AOM is supplied by the DOM so if it's not in the DOM it won't be in the AOM. Post your code here for more specific responses.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually due to a bug in Chrome, which has been fixed. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1214277